# How do I force a SwiftUIView to display pre-loaded data without requiring user to manually alter its state?

Tags: swiftui, combine

**Goal:** to pre-populate a SwiftUI View with data to display once the View is activated.  
 **Note:** these children Views are accessed via the Navigator Link as separate, distinct views.

**Reality:** I had to create a *button to locally change the View status* in order to display the available data.  
I prefer it to be automatically population prior to user activity.

**Question:** How do I implement a local imperative paradigm of forcing the target SwiftUI View to display the available data? 
(i.e. a boiler-plate code to make pre-loading data seen in target views.)

**Observation:** the target SwiftUIView (and siblings) have already been instantiated before the server-supplied data is available when SwiftUIView is actually activated for viewing.

[image]

Comment: Use view model with `ObservableObject/ObservedObject` pattern.

Comment: Don't I have to use classes vs struct (View --> View?).

Comment: Model is kept as struct in view model class, which publishes changes, and view observe those changes rebuilding own body. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/60690441/12299030.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a boolean var in the **EnvironmentObject** that is *accessible across all SwiftUI Views*.

So now I can merely **toggle** this EnvironmentObject's boolean from the origin  which is observed across the application and hence, the target SwiftUI View is *replenish accordingly*.

```
settings.isQueryComplete.toggle()
```